# Variable loss in redirected bash while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, process-substitution

I have the following code

```
for ip in $(ifconfig | awk -F ":"  '/inet addr/{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}')
do
    bytesin=0; bytesout=0;
    while read line
    do
        if [[ $(echo ${line} | awk '{print $1}') == ${ip} ]]
        then
            increment=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}')
            bytesout=$((${bytesout} + ${increment}))
        else
            increment=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $4}')
            bytesin=$((${bytesin} + ${increment}))
        fi
    done < <(pmacct -s | grep ${ip})
    echo "${ip} ${bytesin} ${bytesout}" >> /tmp/bwacct.txt
done
```

Which I would like to print the incremented values to bwacct.txt, but instead the file is full of zeroes:

```
91.227.223.66 0 0
91.227.221.126 0 0
127.0.0.1 0 0
```

My understanding of Bash is that a redirected for loop should preserve variables. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [While Do loop and variables in a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176643/while-do-loop-and-variables-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Debug: if you echo the variables inside the loop, do they contain non-zero values?

Comment: this can be easily solved by some trivial debugging: print all the relevant variables. note: why do you prefer the awkward `${var}` notation?

Comment: This loop runs in the same shell as the final `echo`, so the proposed duplicate does not apply.

Comment: This does not address your problem, but it looks like you can greatly simplify with: `while read ip a b increment c` and save all that `awk` cutting of fields.

Comment: Taking Adam's point, this doesn't look to be the usual case of 'loop is in a sub-shell' which means that the parent does not get the variables.  Taking William's point a step further, it would be simpler, I think, to run `pmacct -s | awk "...' >> /tmp/bwacct.txt`, and I'm not wholly convinced you have to run `pmacct` (and `awk`) once per IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, simplify your script! Usually there are many better ways in bash. Also most of the time you can rely on pure bash solutions instead of running awk or other tools.
Then add some debbuging!
Here is a bit refactored script with debugging

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in "$(ifconfig | grep -oP 'inet addr:\K[0-9.]+')"
do
    bytesin=0
    bytesout=0
    while read -r line
    do
        read -r subIp _ _ increment _ <<< "$line"
        if [[ $subIp == "$ip" ]]
        then
            ((bytesout+=increment))
        else
            ((bytesin+=increment))
        fi
        # some debugging
        echo "line: $line"
        echo "subIp: $subIp"
        echo "bytesin: $bytesin"
        echo "bytesout: $bytesout"
    done <<< "$(pmacct -s | grep "$ip")"
    echo "$ip $bytesin $bytesout" >> /tmp/bwacct.txt
done
```

Much clearer now, huh? :)